# SDL_function that determine the width/height of an SDL_surface?

Tags: c, struct, sdl

I want to  make a structure that contains SDL_Surface , SDL_Rect , the width and the height of the surface,

here's the prototype :

```
typedef struct wall wall;

struct wall {
    SDL_Surface *wall;
    SDL_Rect  wallpos;
    int x;             
    int y;
};
```

the problem is that I dont want to generate the wall.x & wall.y  manually.

Is there any SDL_function that determine the width/height of an SDL_surface right from the dimensions of the image loaded ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a function for this. The width and height of a surface can be read directly from the structure members `w` and `h` (e.g, given `SDL_Surface *s`, you can read `s->w` or `s->h`).

Comment: the width (s->w) it will be an int (surface width) or a pointer toward surface width ?

Comment: wall.w =  wall.s->w ;

    printf("%d \n",&wall.w);  result :  // it does return an the adress of the int

Comment: …because you're taking the address of the variable using `&`

Comment: OMG i'm so sorry ,, i wasn't focused and i mixed it with scanf ,, thank you soo much